# Repeated measure nested within individuals?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

(I'm a beginner so my question could be really dumb ...)
So, I have a set of data that contains 30 schools' variable A and variable B. These two variables were measured repeatedly each year for 10 years. I'm interested in knowing whether these two variables are correlated, but was confused by the repeated measurement that is involved.

I've only learned basic ANOVA and regression, so I searched online and found this "repeated measure nested within individuals ..." Is this the correct method I should use?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this requires a repeated measures analysis. To find the association between the two variables, you need to perform a regression that handles correlation within subjects - standard regression assumes that all of the points are independent.

You could either look into mixed modeling or if you have complete data on all of the schools, then you can use standard least-squares regression but dummy-code the schools as a predictor in the model.

Comment: Don't forget potential autocorrelation within schools.

Comment: You say you are interested in knowing if your two variables, A and B, are correlated.  Typically, ANOVA is used to detect differences in means.  So let me ask for some clarification on what you are interested in:  Are you interested in the size of the correlation between the two variables or the in difference between their means?  If you are interested in correlation, do you want to know if the correlations changed over time?  In any case, how many schools do you have?

Comment: Thanks, Moose and Joel!! I've been searching stuff about mixed modeling and least-squares all day... Realized that all my variables are fixed.

Comment: To clarify: Yes, I'd like to know the size of the correlation between the two variables. The correlation changed over time is not the primary interest. I have 28 schools which are members of an organization (the org only has 28 member schools). Percentage of minority student enrollment and percentage of minority teachers were recorded every year from 2002 to 2011.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is "No, that's not the method".

ANOVA, regression, multi-level models (aka mixed models, but I prefer the former name, as the whole business of fixed and random is amazingly confusing) are all about finding out how the mean of a dependent variable (DV) varies with the independent variables (IVs).  You don't have a DV or IV and you are interested in correlation, not changes in the mean of anything.

Correlation does not assume that the errors are independent (which is why you can't do the usual ANOVA or regression with repeated measures).